# access to a xml file nodes?

Tags: jquery, xml

i have a xml file like this

```
<root>
    <section>
        <state>state one</state>
        <ct>
            <city>first city</city>
            <city>second city</city>
            <city>third city</city>
        </ct>
    </section>
</root>
```

and i want to access to city names in jquery...i have tried s.th like this:

```
var x;
var ct = "";
for(i=1 ; 1=3 ; i++){
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('ct')[0].childNodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
ct += x;
}
$('div').html(ct);
```

BUT, i only have the first city.... and i couldnt access to second and third..
a code like this:

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('ct')[0].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

give me nothing!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned jQuery, you can use [`$.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse the XML to an XML Document, [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to get a jQuery wrapper for that document, [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the `city` nodes, and then do what you like with them (such as using [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get their text):

```js
var doc = $.parseXML(
  '<root>' +
      '<section>' +
          '<state>state one</state>' +
          '<ct>' +
              '<city>first city</city>' +
              '<city>second city</city>' +
              '<city>third city</city>' +
          '</ct>' +
      '</section>' +
  '</root>'
);
var cities = $(doc).find("city");
var cityNames = cities.map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
console.log(cityNames);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

([`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) after `map` converts the jQuery wrapper that `map` returns into a plain array.)

The selector we used in `find` can be more specific. For instance, you specifically looked for `city` elements within a `ct` container; if that's important, our `find` selector should be `ct > city` rather than just `city`:

```js
var doc = $.parseXML(
  '<root>' +
      '<section>' +
          '<state>state one</state>' +
          '<ct>' +
              '<city>first city</city>' +
              '<city>second city</city>' +
              '<city>third city</city>' +
          '</ct>' +
      '</section>' +
  '</root>'
);
var cities = $(doc).find("ct > city");
var cityNames = cities.map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get();
console.log(cityNames);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How many `childNodes` do you see inside the `<ct>` element? Most probably 3. Actually, there are 7 `childNodes` in there. Three of them are your `<city>` elements and additional four are text nodes made of whitespaces (spaces, line breaks, carriage returns) between xml tags.

You should use functions that return array of elements rather than array of nodes (eg. getElementsByTagName).

```
var cities = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('ct')[0].getElementsByTagName('city');
```